# Oracle database Architecture

Tags: oracle, architecture

I need to know to correct order between these following steps, it's hard to find information on the internet on what happens first, i'd be really grateful if someone could give me the answer

A. Oracle searches for a init.ora to determine the configuration
       parameters

B. The proces SMON sometimes executes an instance-recovery

C. memory for the SGA gets allocated and the  background processes that are necessairy get started

D. Oracle searches the database files and redo log files

E. oracle starts an instance

F. oracle searches for the control files with the parameter CONTROL_FILES

Comment: see [Concepts Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/startup.htm#CNCPT955) about database instance startup

Answer (score 1):

A. Oracle searches for a init.ora to determine the configuration
parameters

without a parameterfile, you will get an LRM-00109, ORA-01078 error, and nothing gets started

E. oracle starts an instance

we could argue what exactly starting an instance means, I have just simply put it here because this is the "exact" message that appears first when starting an instance

C. memory for the SGA gets allocated and the background processes that are necessairy get started

background processes like LGWR, DBWR, CKPT, SMON, PMON start in NOMOUNT, way before doing anything with control files...

F. oracle searches for the control files with the parameter CONTROL_FILES

thats the next one when going to MOUNT

D. Oracle searches the database files and redo log files

now tell me, how could the database perform an instance recovery without knowing where the datafiles and redo logs are

B. The proces SMON sometimes executes an instance-recovery

finally an instance recovery is performed, and database gets opened

Answer (score -1):

oracle starts an instance

Oracle searches for a init.ora to determine the configuration
 parameters

oracle searches for the control files with the parameter CONTROL_FILES

memory for the SGA gets allocated and the background processes that are necessairy get started

The proces SMON sometimes executes an instance-recovery

Oracle searches the database files and redo log files

Comment: This is the wrong order ...